# How to standardise date and time contained in single column?

Tags: excel, date

I have a spreadsheet with a single column containing thousands of rows of date and time information that is in two different formats. One has 12-hour time and 24-hour time. Both use American date format (MM-DD-YY).

Example:

```
Row2: 01/18/2015  9:39 PM
Row3: 5/05/2015 22:14
```

I want to get it separated into two columns -- one with date in DD-MM-YYYY format and one with time in 24-hour time.

How can I do this?

Comment: If you narrow the column so the values cannot be displayed, do they *all* turn into ####### or are some truncated text?

Comment: @Jeeped Only the 24-hour time rows turn into ###### as they are recognised by Excel as date/time. the 12-hour time rows are strings.

Comment: Try doing a search and replace on the column; replace two spaces with a single space. Also try using Text-to-Columns, Fixed width, Date - MDY. The Text-to-Columns may be sufficient to reevaluate the date/times into actual date/times and not text. Make sure those are spaces and not non-breaking spaces (CHAR(160))

Comment: If that is imported data, you may have imported some date/times from mm/dd/yyyy into dd/mm/yyyy making Apr 7 into Jul 4. Best to reimport the data using the Text Import Tools and specify the native nature of the date/times as you bring them in.

Answer (score 0):

Adding 2 Columns with the formula works.
[image]